# Firefox date format

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have created a webpage which calculates the weeks and days between two dates.
In chrome this page works and gives me the output of 4 weeks and two days for the dates 01/01/2016 and 01/31/2016 but firefox gives me the output of 130 weeks and two days.
How would I got about changing this to get the output of chrome.
Many thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Time Between Dates Calculator</title>
<script src="dateCalc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calculate the Amount of Time Between Dates:</h1>
<form>
Enter Date 1 (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="date" id="date1" name="date1" required> <br />
Enter Date 2 (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="date" id="date2" name="date2" required> <br />  
<input type="submit" onclick="datecalc()" Value="Get Weeks and days">

</form>
</body>
</html>



***********************************************************************

function datecalc()
{
    firstDate = document.getElementById("date1").value;
    secondDate = document.getElementById("date2").value;
    /*window.alert(firstDate);
    window.alert(secondDate);*/
    firstDateMs = new Date(firstDate).getTime();
    secondDateMs = new Date(secondDate).getTime();

    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    msLeft = (secondDateMs - firstDateMs);
    daysLeft = Math.round(msLeft/msPerDay);
    weeksLeft = Math.round(daysLeft/7);
    total = (daysLeft-(weeksLeft*7))

    window.alert("The difference between these days is: " + weeksLeft + " weeks and " + total + " days.");



}
```

Comment: JFYI, for debug use `console.log(...);` instead of `window.alert(...);`.

Comment: You said 2d date is 31/01/2016 and enter date : mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: You should not round the weeks, only the days.

Answer (score 2):

one solution is to use `.split("/")` on your input strings, then use the 
`new Date(year, month, day);` constructor.

Also January is 0  and December is 11 in Javascript date
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

this will remove any ambiguity from possible string interpretation of the date.

```
firstDate = document.getElementById("date1").value;
secondDate = document.getElementById("date2").value;
/*window.alert(firstDate);
window.alert(secondDate);*/
firstDate.split("/");
secondDate.split("/");
firstDateMs = new Date(parseInt(firstDate[2]), parseInt(firstDate[0]) - 1, parseInt(firstDate[1])).getTime();
secondDateMs = new Date(parseInt(secondDate[2]), parseInt(secondDate[0]) - 1, parseInt(secondDate[1])).getTime();
```

Comment: This now doesn't return anything after hitting submit, any ideas?

Comment: sorry I missed the form instructions stating to be input as mm/dd/yyyy, i'll update the answer

Comment: I now get this, "The difference between these days is: NaN weeks and NaN days." Thanks for all your help

Comment: it is because of the type="date" on your input. chrome handles this nicely and uses a standardized format. and it is the only browser currently supporting the date input without extra script. try using type="text" and see if that helps

Comment: Yeah no luck, out of ideas. Just need to somehow force the format form on firefox as it does exactly what I want on chrome

Comment: Manual parsing is the only sensible solution. There is no need for *parseInt*, just pass the values to the constructor. There is also no need for *getTime*, just subtract one Date from the other. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The submit listener should be on the form, not the submit button, since the form can be submitted without clicking the button. Also, the date strings should be manually parsed to dates and since they depend on user input, the values validated. It can also make life easier if a reference to the form is passed by the handler so controls are accessed by name rather than *getElementById*.

Input type date is not well supported and creates more issues than it solves for now, so better to use type text (or use your own date picker). The following uses input type text and manually parses and validates the string in m/d/y format.

For a real form, it would be better to validate each date separately and put an error message for the one(s) that are invalid, also to echo the parsed date to the screen so the user can see that the code is using the date as they expect (e.g. 1/2/2016 comes out as 2 January not 1 February).

Some code…

```js
function datecalc(form) {
  var d1 = parseMDY(form.date1.value);
  var d2 = parseMDY(form.date2.value);
  var msDay = 8.64e7;
  var msWeek = msDay * 7;
  var result;
  
  // Deal with in valid input
  if (isNaN(+d1) || isNaN(+d2)) {
    result = 'Invalid date';
  } else {
  
    // Get weeks and days
    var diff = d2 - d1;
    result = (diff/msWeek | 0) + ' weeks ' + 
             Math.round((diff % msWeek)/msDay | 0) + ' days';
  }
  
  // Should return an array of say [weeks, days] and leave formatting
  // to some other function.
  form.result.value = result;
}

function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : new Date(NaN);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="datecalc(this); return false;">
  Enter Date 1 (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="text" name="date1" value="3/1/2016"><br>
  Enter Date 2 (mm/dd/yyyy): <input type="text" name="date2" value="3/23/2016"><br>  
  <input type="reset"> <input type="submit" Value="Get Weeks and days"><br>
  <input type="text" name="result" readonly>
</form>
```

I guess you're rounding the days to remove daylight saving errors, be careful with that. An alternative is to get the difference in days from the date values and not create date objects at all. That removes any issues with DST (but validating the dates takes about 3 lines more code).